# Python turtle leaves dots while moving

Tags: python, turtle-graphics, python-turtle

I am trying to make Pac-man Game using turtle. When I run my code it shows small dots. While moving turtle press w to go up-ward and you can find the small dot at bottom of player.

```
from turtle import *

class creator(Turtle):
    def __init__(self, row, col, sprit, colorcode, width, height):
        Turtle.__init__(self)
        self.row=row
        self.col=col
        self.colorcode=colorcode
        self.sprit=sprit
        x, y=self.coords(row, col)
        self.color(colorcode)
        self.shape(sprit)
        self.shapesize(width, height, 0)
        self.pu()
        self.speed(0)
        self.goto(x, y)

    def coords(self, row, col):
        x=(-250+(col*25))
        y=(137.5-(row*25))
        return x, y

    def left(self):
        if ((self.xcor()-25, self.ycor()) not in game.running.walls):
            if ((self.xcor()-25, self.ycor()) in game.running.foods):
                foodcol=int(((self.xcor()-25)+250)/25)
                foodrow=int((137.5-self.ycor())/25)
                game.food[foodrow, foodcol].hideturtle()
                game.score+=1
                game.running.writer.clear()
                game.running.writer.write('score:{}'.format(game.score), font=('Arial',18,'bold'),move=False)
            self.goto(self.xcor()-25, self.ycor())

    def right(self):
        if ((self.xcor()+25, self.ycor()) not in game.running.walls):
            if ((self.xcor()+25,self.ycor()) in game.running.foods):
                foodcol=int(((self.xcor()+25)+250)/25)
                foodrow=int((137.5-self.ycor())/25)
                game.food[foodrow,foodcol].hideturtle()
                game.score+=1
                game.running.writer.clear()
                game.running.writer.write('score:{}'.format(game.score), font=('Arial', 18, 'bold'), move=False)
            self.goto(self.xcor()+25, self.ycor())

    def up(self):
        if ((self.xcor(), self.ycor()+25) not in game.running.walls):
            if ((self.xcor(), self.ycor()+25) in game.running.foods):
                foodcol=int(((self.xcor())+250)/25)
                foodrow=int((137.5-(self.ycor()+25))/25)
                game.food[foodrow, foodcol].hideturtle()
                game.score+=1
                game.running.writer.clear()
                game.running.writer.write('score:{}'.format(game.score), font=('Arial', 18, 'bold'), move=False)
            self.goto(self.xcor(), self.ycor()+25)

    def down(self):
        if ((self.xcor(), self.ycor()-25) not in game.running.walls):
            if ((self.xcor(), self.ycor()-25) in game.running.foods):
                foodcol=int(((self.xcor())+250)/25)
                foodrow=int((137.5-(self.ycor()-25))/25)
                game.food[foodrow, foodcol].hideturtle()
                game.score+=1
                game.running.writer.clear()
                game.running.writer.write('score:{}'.format(game.score), font=('Arial', 18, 'bold'), move=False)
            self.goto(self.xcor(), self.ycor()-25)
class running:
    def __init__(self, game):
        self.game=game
        self.writer=Turtle(visible=False)
        self.writer.pu()
        self.writer.color('blue')
        self.writer.goto(240, 140)
        print('righthere')
        self.writer.write('score:{}'.format(game.score), font=('Arial', 18, 'bold'), move=False)
        self.walls=[]
        self.foods=[]
        self.setup(game)
        listen()
        onkey(game.player[9, 9].left, 'a')
        onkey(game.player[9, 9].right, 'd')
        onkey(game.player[9, 9].up, 'w')
        onkey(game.player[9, 9].down, 's')

    def setup(self, game):
        self.game=game
        for row in range(11):
            for col in range(20):
                if level[row][col]==1:
                    self.walls.append((game.wall[row, col].xcor(), game.wall[row, col].ycor()))
##                elif level[row][col]==2:
##                    self.enemy[(row, col)]=creator(row, col, 'triangle', 'red',1,1)
##                elif level[row][col]==3:
##                    self.player[(row, col)]=creator(row, col, 'circle', 'yellow',1,1)
                elif level[row][col]==0:
                    self.foods.append((game.food[row, col].xcor(), game.food[row,col].ycor()))
##                
class pacman:
    def __init__(self):
        self.wall={}
        self.player={}
        self.food={}
        self.enemy={}
        self.score=0
        win.tracer(False)
        self.setup()
        win.tracer(True)
        self.running=running(self)

    def setup(self):
        for row in range(11):
            for col in range(20):
                if level[row][col]==1:
                    self.wall[(row, col)]=creator(row, col, 'square', 'blue',1,1)
                elif level[row][col]==2:
                    self.enemy[(row, col)]=creator(row, col, 'triangle', 'red',1,1)
                elif level[row][col]==3:
                    self.player[(row, col)]=creator(row,col, 'circle', 'yellow',1,1)
                else:
                    self.food[(row,col)]=creator(row, col, 'circle', 'white',0.1,0.1)

        
level=[[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
       [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
       [1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1],
       [1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1],
       [1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1],
       [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
       [1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1],
       [1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1],
       [1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1],
       [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
       [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]]

win =Screen()
win.bgcolor('black')
game=pacman()
win.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I reworked nearly every aspect of your program and couldn't spot the culprit for the yellow artifacts (part of the pacman itself.)  So, I put a band-aid on the code by leaving `tracer()` off for the entire program and doing explicit screen `update()` calls.

[EDIT: @AnnZen's answer identifies the source of the glitch.]

I also replaced your redudant entity location logic by checking the original `dict` rather than the `list` cache.  This simplified the logic, and eliminated some potential floating point issues. And, checking dictionaries is actually faster than checking lists.

Plus lots of other changes to simplify and stabilize the code:

```
from turtle import Screen, Turtle

FONT = ('Arial', 18, 'bold')

class Creator(Turtle):
    def __init__(self, row, col, sprite, colorcode, width, height):
        super().__init__(shape=sprite)
        self.row = row
        self.col = col

        self.color(colorcode)
        self.shapesize(width, height)
        self.penup()
##      self.speed('fastest')
        self.goto(self.coords(row, col))

    @staticmethod
    def coords(row, col):
        x = col * 25 - 250
        y = 137.5 - row * 25

        return x, y

    @staticmethod
    def inv_coords(x, y):
        col = round((x + 250) / 25)
        row = round((137.5 - y) / 25)

        return row, col

    def go_left(self):
        screen.onkey(None, 'a')  # disable handler inside handler

        position = self.xcor() - 25, self.ycor()

        key = self.inv_coords(*position)

        if key not in game.wall:

            if key in game.food:
                game.food[key].hideturtle()
                game.increment_score()

            self.goto(self.coords(*key))
            screen.update()

        screen.onkey(self.go_left, 'a')

    def go_right(self):
        screen.onkey(None, 'd')

        position = self.xcor() + 25, self.ycor()

        key = self.inv_coords(*position)

        if key not in game.wall:

            if key in game.food:
                game.food[key].hideturtle()
                game.increment_score()

            self.goto(self.coords(*key))
            screen.update()

        screen.onkey(self.go_right, 'd')

    def go_up(self):
        screen.onkey(None, 'w')

        position = self.xcor(), self.ycor() + 25

        key = self.inv_coords(*position)

        if key not in game.wall:

            if key in game.food:
                game.food[key].hideturtle()
                game.increment_score()

            self.goto(self.coords(*key))
            screen.update()

        screen.onkey(self.go_up, 'w')

    def go_down(self):
        screen.onkey(None, 's')

        position = self.xcor(), self.ycor() - 25

        key = self.inv_coords(*position)

        if key not in game.wall:

            if key in game.food:
                game.food[key].hideturtle()
                game.increment_score()

            self.goto(self.coords(*key))
            screen.update()

        screen.onkey(self.go_down, 's')

class Running:
    def __init__(self, game):
        self.game = game

        self.writer = Turtle(visible=False)
        self.writer.penup()
        self.writer.color('blue')
        self.writer.goto(240, 140)
        self.writer.write("score:{}".format(game.score), font=FONT)

##      self.setup()

        screen.onkey(game.player[9, 9].go_left, 'a')
        screen.onkey(game.player[9, 9].go_right, 'd')
        screen.onkey(game.player[9, 9].go_up, 'w')
        screen.onkey(game.player[9, 9].go_down, 's')
        screen.listen()

    def setup(self):

        for row in range(11):
            for col in range(20):
                if level[row][col] == 0:
                    pass
                elif level[row][col] == 1:
                    pass
##              elif level[row][col] == 2:
##                  self.enemy[(row, col)] = Creator(row, col, 'triangle', 'red', 1, 1)
##              elif level[row][col] == 3:
##                  self.player[(row, col)] = Creator(row, col, 'circle', 'yellow', 1, 1)

class Pacman:
    def __init__(self):
        self.wall = {}
        self.player = {}
        self.food = {}
        self.enemy = {}

        self.score = 0

        screen.tracer(False)
        self.setup()
        screen.update()
        self.running = Running(self)

    def setup(self):
        for row in range(11):
            for col in range(20):
                if level[row][col] == 1:
                    self.wall[(row, col)] = Creator(row, col, 'square', 'blue', 1, 1)
                elif level[row][col] == 2:
                    self.enemy[(row, col)] = Creator(row, col, 'triangle', 'red', 1, 1)
                elif level[row][col] == 3:
                    self.player[(row, col)] = Creator(row, col, 'circle', 'yellow', 1, 1)
                else:
                    self.food[(row, col)] = Creator(row, col, 'circle', 'white', 0.1, 0.1)

    def increment_score(self):
        self.score += 1
        self.running.writer.clear()
        self.running.writer.write("score:{}".format(self.score), font=FONT)

level = [
    [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
    [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
    [1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1],
    [1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1],
    [1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1],
    [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
    [1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1],
    [1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1],
    [1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1],
    [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
    [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
]

screen = Screen()
screen.bgcolor('black')
game = Pacman()
screen.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1):

The fix is super easy, barely an inconvenience:

You see, this is a small glitch in the `turtle.shapesize` method, you have

```
self.shapesize(width, height, 0)
```

It's the `0` that tripped the method up. Instead, omit the `0`, or use the default value for the outline, `None`:

```
self.shapesize(width, height)
```

or

```
self.shapesize(width, height, None)
```

*No `tracer` band-aid needed!*

Comment: Nice catch Ann!  (+1)  The OP was trying to specify "no outline" but the reality is, a value of `0`, or `None`, or '1', or simply no `outline` argument, all produce an outline of width `1` (but only `0` produces the artifacts.)  Use a different color for the outline to see this.  The underlying Tk can handle no outline, but Python tkinter would have to convert 0 to an empty string token for Tk.  Turtle glosses over the issue by documenting that `outline` is a positive integer, thus no zeros.